# Pspicture is not centered

Tags: floats, pstricks, subfloats, pspicture

I am trying to print a `pspicture` as a `subfigure` in a `figure`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfigure[]{%
    \centering
    \framebox[1\linewidth][t]{above}}\\
  \subfigure[pspicture]{%
    \centering
    \begin{pspicture}
      \centering
      \psframe[linewidth=0.8pt,fillstyle=none](0, 0)(15,0.5)
    \end{pspicture}
  }\\
  \subfigure[]{%
    \centering
    \framebox[1\linewidth][t]{below}
  }
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{pspicture}
      \centering
      \psframe[linewidth=0.8pt,fillstyle=none](0, 0)(15,0.5)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And, here is the output (please ignore the color) of the first figure:

[image]

We can notice that the 1er subfigure and the 3rd subfigure are well placed; they are left- and right- aligned with the page. Whereas, it is not the case for the pspicture. The output of the second figure that I omit here also clearly shows that the pspicture is not centered.

Does anyone know what happened? and how to correct this?

Comment: Please post a minimal example. (`\subfigure` is defined how? Or by which package? Your class is...? You are using what to extend float management, if anything? Etc.) We cannot reproduce what you see from the code you have given :(.

Comment: Tried for a while but can't figure out how to complete your code.

Comment: Your `pspicture`'s width is wider than \textwidth; using `\subfigure[pspicture]{\begin{pspicture}(\textwidth,0.5)
    \psframe[linewidth=0.8pt,fillstyle=none](0, 0)(15,0.5)
  \end{pspicture}} ` will make the picture strat from the left margin, but since it's too wide it will still protrude to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying coordinates for `pspicture` it uses `10cm x 10cm`! However, package `subfigure is obsolete, use`subfig` instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{%
            \centering
            \framebox[\linewidth][t]{above}}\\
        \subfloat[pspicture]{%
            \centering
            \begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,0.5)
            \psframe[linewidth=0.8pt,fillstyle=none](0, 0)(\linewidth,0.5)
            \end{pspicture}
        }\\
        \subfloat[]{%
            \framebox[\linewidth][t]{below}
        }
    \end{figure*}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,0.5)
        \psframe[linewidth=0.8pt,fillstyle=none](0, 0)(\linewidth,0.5)
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]